# How to start multiple instances of the same module/function under the Supervisor behavior in erlang?

Tags: erlang

Having a module/function **mymodule** , how to start it multiple times under the [supervisor](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#type-child_spec) behavior ?

I need for example 2 instances of the **same process** (mymodule) to be started concurrently. I called the children identifiers as **child1** and **child2**. They both point to the **mymodule** module that I want to start. I have specified two different functions to to start each instance of the worker process "mymodule" ( start_link1 and start_link2 )

```
-module(my_supervisor).

-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0, init/1]).

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, _Arg = []).

init([]) ->
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 10, 10},
          [{child1,
            {mymodule, start_link1, []},
            permanent,
            10000,
            worker,
            [mymodule]}
          ,
           {child2,
            {mymodule, start_link2, []},
            permanent,
            10000,
            worker,
            [mymodule]}
          ]}}.
```

The **worker** has two distinguished start_link functions ( start_link1 and start_link2 ) for testing purposes:

```
-module(mymodule).
-behaviour(gen_server).

start_link1() ->
    log_something("at link 1"),
    gen_server:start_link({global, child1}, ?MODULE, [], []).

start_link2() ->
    log_something("at link 2"),
    gen_server:start_link({global, child2}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
    ....
```

With the above I can see in my log the message "at link 1" but it does reveal "at link 2" anywhere. It also does not perform anything in the instance of link1 : just dies apparently.

The only scenario that works is when the name "child1" **matches** the worker module name "mymodule".

Comment: If you register the name of the process started with mymodule:start_link you will get this error as there can be only one process with the same registered name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MilleBessö asks are you trying to two processes which have the same registered name? Does `mymodule:start_link` register the mymodule process under a fixed name? If so then trying to start a second one will cause a clash. Ot are you trying to start multiple `my_supervisor` supervisors? Then you will also get a name clash. You have not included the code for `my_module`.

Remember you can only have one process registered under a name. This holds for both local registered processes and those registered using `global`.

**EDIT:** Does the supervisor die as well?

A `gen_server`, and all other behaviours, aren't considered to be properly started until the `init` callback has completed and returned a correct value (`{ok,State}`). So if there is an error in `mymodule:init/1` then this will crash the child process **before** it has been initialised and the supervisor will give up. While a supervisor can and will restart children when they die it does require that they all start correctly. From [supervisor:start_link/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_link-3)

> If the supervisor and its child processes are successfully created (i.e. if all child process start functions return {ok,Child}, {ok,Child,Info}, or ignore) the function returns {ok,Pid}, where Pid is the pid of the supervisor. If there already exists a process with the specified SupName the function returns {error,{already_started,Pid}}, where Pid is the pid of that process.
>
> If Module:init/1 returns ignore, this function returns ignore as well and the supervisor terminates with reason normal. If Module:init/1 fails or returns an incorrect value, this function returns {error,Term} where Term is a term with information about the error, and the supervisor terminates with reason Term.

I don't know if this is the problem but it give the same behaviour as you get.

Comment: I updated the description to show what I did on the worker code and how I am passing an identifier to it, so it knows what to register. I am indeed trying to register the same process, but on a different identifier name. My objective is to use the supervisor behavior as a process pool, since it handles the startup/shutdown and restart of its children processes.

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs for `supervisor:start_link()`. The first parameter you pass in here is the name it uses to register with `global`, which provides a global `name -> pid` lookup. Since this must be unique, your second process fails to start, since the name is already taken.

Edit: Here is link to the docs: http://erldocs.com/R15B/stdlib/supervisor.html?i=5&search=supervisor:start#start_link/3

Comment: So if I generate a random name and atomize it, then it should work ? Are there any negative consequences for doing that ?

Comment: It only uses `global` if the first argument is of the form `{global,?MODULE}`. Here it is `{local,?MODULE}` so it only does a simple registered name.

Comment: @gextra: Atom names are *never* garbage-collected, so unless you're only spawning the process a small number of times, you definitely don't want to pollute your atom table with random entries. Your whole VM could crash.

Comment: please see updated detailed description of the problem. thanks

Comment: @gextra: Why don't you pass in the unique id you already have in the supervisor to the `start_link` function?

Comment: I did already try that already, with same results. The test case above was just to make it more explicit that I am using the appropriate identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Check also [simple-one-for-one](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#id72445) supervisor restart scenario. It allows to start multiple processes with same child specification in more automated way.